# Is there a better way to sort and display an array of dates by day of the week in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I currently have a simple scheduling system where a user can select from 20 different time slots to make an appointment. I wanted to update that to look and function better as it's quite simple in its current form. My idea is to take the current iteration and make it so the days of the week for the appointments dynamically update based on the data held within an array of available appointments (which has more than 20 in it, but I only show 20).

My issue is that I've spent some time with this and I'm starting to realize that I'm writing a lot of code for what could probably be done in a more simple manner. Right now, the code I have written looks at the current place of the array (since index 0 may not have anything in it due to it not being an available time slot), and then loops through to find the next day to display. That works, but I'm not sure how to get the values that are associated with that date.

The array holds dates/time that look like this:
**2020-07-27 17:00:00**

See my before and after screenshots for what I'm trying to do for more clarification:

**Before:**
[image: Before]

**After:**
[image: After]

So I'm trying to take it from the two columns where the dates are organized in descending order to where it displays the available time slots (and all days) in a more attractive and easy to read way.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Code:

```
<?php

//Get value of first entry (not necessarily index 0 since its been cleaned to remove unavailable dates)
$firstEntryValue = current($program_final);

//Convert date to day of the week                                           
$dayOfWeek = date("l", strtotime($firstEntryValue));
                                                                              
//Output for verification                                                                                              
echo '<p>';                                                                                         
print_r($dayOfWeek);                                                                                             
echo '</p>';
                                                                                                                                                                            
//Set to null for first instance                                                                                            
$nextDay = $dayOfWeek;                                                                                  
                                                                                            
//Find next day - 1                                                                                     
do {                                                                                                    
    $nextDate = next($program_final);                                                                                               
    $nextDay = date("l", strtotime($nextDate));                                                                                           
} while ($nextDay == $dayOfWeek);
                                                                                                                                                                                        
//Set
$dayOfWeek = $nextDay;                                                                                      
                                                                                            
//Output of Next day                                                                                            
echo '<p>';                                                                                         
print_r($nextDay);                                                                                               
echo '</p>';
                                                                                                                                                                                        
//Set                                                                                           
$dayOfWeek = $nextDay;
                                                                                                                
//Find next day - 2                                                                                         
do {                                                                                                     
    $nextDate = next($program_final);                                                                                           
    $nextDay = date("l", strtotime($nextDate));                                                                                             
 } while ($nextDay == $dayOfWeek);                                                                                  
                                                                                            
//Output of Next day                                                                                                  
echo '<p>';                                                                                         
print_r($nextDay);                                                                                        
echo '</p>';
                                                                                                                                                                                        
//Set                                                                                       
$dayOfWeek = $nextDay;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
//Loop for appointment display                                                                              
foreach (array_slice($program_final, 0, 10) as &$value) {                                                                                           
     echo '<div class="large-6 cell">';                                                                                             
       echo '<div class="grid-x align-center grid-padding-x align-middle">'                                                                                                     
         echo '<div class="auto shrink cell">';                                                                                                     
           echo '<input name="apptime" value="' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($value)) . '"  type="radio" required>';                                                                                         
          echo '</div>';                                                                                            
     echo '<div class="auto cell">';                                                                                            
        echo '<p style="text-transform: uppercase;">'. date("M j Y, g:i A", strtotime($value)) .'</p>';                                                                                  
     echo '</div>';                                                                                         
  echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
};
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can map the first array into an associative array that has as key the day and as value another array of available hours.

To accomplish this, you could so something like the following:

```
$program_final = ['2020-07-27 17:00:00', '2020-07-27 18:00:00'];
$dates = [];
/**
 * Transforms from the ['2020-07-27 17:00:00', '2020-07-27 18:00:00', ...] format to 
 * the ['2020-07-27' => ['17:00:00', '18:00:00', '20:00:00'], '2020-07-29' => ['19:00:00']]
 */
foreach ($program_final as $value) {
    [$date, $hour] = explode(" ", $value);
    if (!isset($dates[$date])) {
        $dates[$date] = [];
    }

    $dates[$date][] = $hour;
}

foreach ($dates as $date => $hours) {
    print_r(date("l", strtotime($date)));     
    foreach($hours as $hour) {
        $date_val = strtotime($date . ' ' . $hour);

        echo '<div class="large-6 cell">';                                                                                             
            echo '<div class="grid-x align-center grid-padding-x align-middle">';                                                                                                     
                echo '<div class="auto shrink cell">';                                                                                                     
                    echo '<input name="apptime" value="' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date_val) . '"  type="radio" required>';                                                                                         
                echo '</div>';                                                                                            
                echo '<div class="auto cell">';                                                                                            
                    echo '<p style="text-transform: uppercase;">'. date("M j Y, g:i A", $date_val) .'</p>';                                                                                  
                echo '</div>';                                                                                         
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }                                                  
};
```

This way within the first for loop you could output the day, and in the second or inner loop, you have every available hour for that day.
If you need to have it in separate elements you will need to run two separate loops, one for outputting the days in the tabs, and the second for the hours in the section below.

**Edit:**
An older PHP version compatible code:

```
<?php

$program_final = ['2020-07-27 17:00:00', '2020-07-27 18:00:00'];
$dates = [];
/**
 * Transforms from the ['2020-07-27 17:00:00', '2020-07-27 18:00:00', ...] format to 
 * the ['2020-07-27' => ['17:00:00', '18:00:00', '20:00:00'], '2020-07-29' => ['19:00:00']]
 */
foreach ($program_final as $value) {
    $splitted = explode(" ", $value);
    $date = $splitted[0];
    $hour = $splitted[1];

    if (!isset($dates[$date])) {
        $dates[$date] = [];
    }

    $dates[$date][] = $hour;
}

foreach ($dates as $date => $hours) {
    print_r(date("l", strtotime($date)));     
    foreach($hours as $hour) {
        $date_val = strtotime($date . ' ' . $hour);

        echo '<div class="large-6 cell">';                                                                                             
            echo '<div class="grid-x align-center grid-padding-x align-middle">';                                                                                                     
                echo '<div class="auto shrink cell">';                                                                                                     
                    echo '<input name="apptime" value="' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date_val) . '"  type="radio" required>';                                                                                         
                echo '</div>';                                                                                            
                echo '<div class="auto cell">';                                                                                            
                    echo '<p style="text-transform: uppercase;">'. date("M j Y, g:i A", $date_val) .'</p>';                                                                                  
                echo '</div>';                                                                                         
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }                                                  
};
```

Comment: That might just be what I need, I wasn't sure how to take the array and break it into its pieces. I'll give it a go!

Comment: It seems that for some reason the first foreach causes the page to not load, I haven't seen anything wrong with it (from my limited experience with  PHP). Do you have any ideas why it may not be loading? @Aleksandar Pavlov

Comment: @Omega636 make sure that the $program_final is defined and available. Also, please provide the PHP version you are working with.

Comment: I currently do not have access to my server to check what the PHP version is.

$program_final is defined and accessible, it looks like the issue is with [$date, $hour] = explode(" ", $value); 

I'm not sure if it is supposed to be = or ==, but I did change it to == and the page now loads. @Aleksandar Pavlov

Comment: The php version is  7.0

Comment: @Omega636 it should be just 1 equal = since we're assigning values. I updated the response to be compatible with older PHP versions. Please check it now.

Comment: @Aleksandar Pavlov Gotcha, I figured we were assigning values so I had a feeling the == was wrong. Thank you for the update, that seems to be working now!